# Pegar a ultima versão do Mozilla Firefox através de script

Tags: shell-script

Estava fazendo um script que busca a ultima versão do Mozilla Firefox na URL

```
#!/bin/bash

base_url="https://download-installer.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases/"
href_pattern='s/.*href="\([^"]*\).*/\1/p'

last_version=$(curl -s $base_url | sed -n $href_pattern | sort -V | tail -n 1)

echo last_url=$base_url$last_version
```

ele esta buscando da seguinte forma:

```
last_url=https://download-installer.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases//pub/firefox/releases/stub/
```

quando deveria pegar:

```
last_url=http://download-installer.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases/60.0b3/`
```

como eu pego a ultima pasta da versão do mesmo no link?

Comment: Sempre que colocar código em uma das suas perguntas selecione-o e formate-o com o atalho `Ctrl+K` ou com o botão `{}` do editor da pergunta

Comment: Olá. Você deseja saber qual a última versão, neste caso 60.b3, ou apenas baixar a última versão do firefox?

Comment: primeiramente estava tentando fazer ele buscar a ultima versao do mozilla para depois baixar..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respondendo à sua pergunta, o script a seguir utiliza o esquema de URL, disponível na URL https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/latest-beta/README.txt, que define como baixar a última versão beta do firefox no sistema operacional e linguagem desejada.

O script aceita três argumentos opcionais, sistema operacional, linguagem e versão (stable ou beta):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Programa para baixar ultima versao do firefox utilizando
# o esquema de URL https://download-installer.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases/latest/README.txt
# uso: baixafirefox [SISTEMA_OPERACIONAL] [LINGUAGEM] [TIPO]
#      Valores das opcoes :
#               SISTEMA_OPERACIONAL = win (default), win64, osx, linux e linux64
#               LINGUAGEM = pt-BR (default), en-US, fr, es-AR etc
#               TIPO = firefox-beta-latest (default) firefox-latest
#
# exemplo 1: baixar versao beta, para linux 64 bits, em ingles:
#            $ baixafirefox linux64 en-US 
# exemplo 2: baixar versao beta, para windows em portugues (valores padrao)
#            $ baixafirefox
# exemplo 3: baixar versao estável, para windows em portugues (valores padrao)
#            $ baixafirefox win pt-BR firefox-latest
#
### VARIAVEIS
os=$1
linguagem=$2
produto=$3

### PRINCIPAL
# popular variaveis com valores padrao de sistema operacional e 
# linguagem, caso argumentos nao tenham sido passados 
[ -z $os ] && os=win
[ -z $linguagem ] && linguagem=pt-BR
[ -z $produto ] && produto=firefox-beta-latest
echo "https://download.mozilla.org/?product=$produto&os=$os&lang=$linguagem"
wget --content-disposition https://download.mozilla.org/?product=$produto\&os=$os\&lang=$linguagem
```

O script acima é só um ponto de partida e deve ser melhorado de acordo co msua necessidade.

Comment: fiz o teste do seu programa e ele esta baixando a versao 59.0.1 e a versao atual é 60.0b5. o script que eu tentei mostrar acima deveria buscar sempre pela ultima versao disponivel na url. por essa razao utilizei aquela url..

Comment: Ok. O link acima pega a versão estável mais recente. Se você quiser pegar a versão beta mais recente, basta trocar o parametro product=firefox-latest por product=firefox-beta. Atualizarei o script e adicionarei esta opcao